# How to identify the source of a Google Service Account

Tags: google-account, google-analytics, google-cloud

I inherited some websites that have Google Analytics configured on them. There are various users that have access to these analytics. One user is `<id_here>@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. I gather that this is a Google "service account" for something to get programmatic access to the analytics.

Is there a way I can track down this service account to see more information about where it came from and what it is used for?

Comment: Questions about Google Analytics are better suited for [webmasters.se]. Questions about Google Service accounts are better suited for other [se] sites. Post a question in [meta.se] to ask for a site recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no way for you to track down who owns this service account.   The only way you can see it would be to login to the Google account that has access.

The best thing you can do would be to not the service account email address and send an email around the company seeing if anyone knows who owns it.

Optionally you could also remove it and wait for someone to scream.   A service account having access without knowing who is controlling it is probably not a good idea it could be someone that has left the company who knows what they could be doing with the data.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking the "scream test" may be the only option here.

Comment: Its worked well for me in the past.   I have a issue out with Google for about six years asking for the ability to add notes on users so that I could keep track of things.